# Custom fields created after data already entered

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I'm having an issue with creating custom fields after data has already been added to the DB. I've been looking at this for a while and my brain has shut down. I'll try and explain the best I can.

I have 2 tables, custom_fields and custom_fields_values. I also sort these fields via a table column. When I pull them from the db I have to join the tables in order to have the results show in the same order as the fields. If I don't then data gets mixed up.

```
$customfield = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM custom_fields ORDER BY fieldorder ASC");
$customfield->execute();
$customfield = $customfield->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$customfieldvals = $pdo->prepare("SELECT vals.* FROM custom_fields_values vals JOIN custom_fields fields ON fields.id = vals.fieldid WHERE vals.related_system=:relsystem ORDER BY fields.fieldorder ASC");
$customfieldvals->bindParam(':relsystem', $get_system['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$customfieldvals->execute();
$customfieldvals = $customfieldvals->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I then have a `foreach` loop that does properly display the data. The issue is, when I add a new custom field that does not have a value because it was created in the custom_fields table, but NOT in the custom_fields_values table so it doesn't match at `ON fields.id = vals.fieldid`. If I resort the fields while this has no value, it takes the value of another field. Essentially, because it doesn't match at the `id` level of fields and `fieldid` of values, everything gets messed up.

How can I make it to where if it does not have a value row created, it will just show `NULL` no matter what instead of taking the value of another field?

**EDIT**

Am I going about this the right way or is there a better way to have the custom field value follow the custom field rather than the `JOIN` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Left Join` in to your query. Left Join will return null If it does not found value for custom field into custom_fields_values table.

So Query will look like this.

```
$customfieldvals = $pdo->prepare("SELECT vals.* FROM custom_fields_values vals LEFT JOIN custom_fields fields ON fields.id = vals.fieldid WHERE vals.related_system=:relsystem ORDER BY fields.fieldorder ASC");
```

Comment: Did you try with `Right Join` ?

Comment: @CrunchyToast you can also try this query. `SELECT vals.* FROM custom_fields fields
LEFT JOIN custom_fields_values vals  ON fields.id = vals.fieldid 
WHERE vals.related_system=:relsystem 
ORDER BY fields.fieldorder ASC`

Comment: Your most recent comment was very close to what I did to resolve this. I'll add the answer below. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think about this initially, but instead of calling a separate query for just values I totally removed the `$customfieldvals` query and changed the `$customfield` query. This instead locks the value to the field rather than just linking them.

```
$customfield = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM custom_fields fields LEFT JOIN custom_fields_values vals ON fields.id = vals.fieldid WHERE vals.related_system=:relsystem ORDER BY fieldorder ASC");
$customfields->bindParam(':relsystem', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$customfield->execute();
$customfield = $customfield->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and then my `foreach`:

```
foreach ($customfield as $fields) {...
```

This allowed me to call

`$fields['value']`

rather than

`$customfieldvals[$key]['value']`